# How do I break inline-blocks into 2 lines maximum?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have an indefinite number of blocks that I want to place inside a container and have them **break into 2 lines maximum** and then be able to scroll ***horizontally*** across those 2 lines of blocks.

I'm trying the code you see in the snippet but it's not working. It's placing all blocks in one single line.

```js
let container = document.getElementById('container')
let numOfBlocks = 20 // could be any number
let blockSize = 200
let blockRightMargin = 10
let maxContainerWidth = Math.ceil(numOfBlocks/2)*(blockSize+blockRightMargin)

while (numOfBlocks) {
  let block = document.createElement('div')
  block.className = 'block'
  container.appendChild(block)
  numOfBlocks--
}

container.style['max-width'] = maxContainerWidth + 'px'
```

```css
#horizontal-scroller {
  position: relative;
  float: left;
  height: auto;
  width: 100%;
  max-width: 420px;
  overflow-x: auto;
}

#container {
  position: relative;
  float: left;
  height: auto;
  width: auto;
  text-align: left;
  font-size: 0;
  white-space: nowrap;
}

.block {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
  margin-right: 10px;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
  background: lime;
}
```

```html
<div id="horizontal-scroller">
  <div id="container"></div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use CSS grid:

```css
#horizontal-scroller {
  position: relative;
  max-width: 420px;
  overflow-x: auto;
  display: grid;
  grid-template-rows: 1fr 1fr; /* 2 rows */
  grid-auto-flow: column;
  gap: 10px;
}

#horizontal-scroller > div {
  width: 150px;
  height: 150px;
  background: lime;
}
```

```html
<div id="horizontal-scroller">
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
</div>
```